# Calendar-like UICollectionView - how to add left inset before first item only?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have the following `UICollectionView`:
It has `vertical` scrolling, `1 section` and `31 items`.
It has the basic setup and I am calculating `itemSize` to fit exactly `7 per row`.
Currently it looks like this:

[image]

However, I would like to make an inset before first item, so that the layout is even and there are the same number of items in first and last row. This is static and will always contain 31 items, so I am basically trying to add left space/inset before first item, so that it looks like this:

[image]

I have tried using a custom `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method:

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int)
```

But since there is only 1 section with 31 rows, it insets all of the rows, not just the first.
I know I could probably add two more "blank" items, but I feel like there is a better solution I may not be aware of. Any ideas?

EDIT: I've tried Tarun's answer, but this doesn't work. Origin of first item changes, but the rest stays as is, therefore first overlaps the second and the rest remain as they were. Shifting them all doesn't work either. I ended up with:

[image]

Comment: Do you have ALWAYS 31 items?

Comment: Yes, @mahan, always. But I would like to avoid adding 2 empty rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Taran's suggestion, I've decided to use a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout. Here is a generic answer that works for any number of items in the collectionView, as well as any inset value:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return nil }
    guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return nil }

    var newAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

    for attribute in attributes {
        if let cellAttribute = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: attribute.indexPath) {
            let itemSize = cellAttribute.frame.size.width + self.minimumInteritemSpacing
            let targetOriginX = cellAttribute.frame.origin.x + CGFloat(self.itemInset) * itemSize

            if targetOriginX <= collectionView.bounds.size.width {
                cellAttribute.frame.origin.x = targetOriginX
            } else {
                let shiftedPosition = lround(Double((targetOriginX / itemSize).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: CGFloat(self.numberOfColumns))))

                cellAttribute.frame.origin.x = itemSize * CGFloat(shiftedPosition)
                cellAttribute.frame.origin.y += itemSize
            }

            newAttributes.append(cellAttribute)
        }
    }

    return newAttributes
}
```

where:

- `self.itemInset` is the value we want to inset from the left (2 for my initial question, but it can be any number from `0` to the `number of columns-1`)
- `self.numberOfColumns` is - as the name suggests - number of columns in the collectionView. This pertains to the number of days in my example and would always be equal to `7`, but one might want this to be a generic value for some other use case.

Just for the sake of the completeness, I provide a method that calculates a size for my callendar collection view, based on the number of columns (days):

```
private func collectionViewItemSize() -> CGSize {
    let dimension = self.collectionView.frame.size.width / CGFloat(Constants.numberOfDaysInWeek) - Constants.minimumInteritemSpacing
    return CGSize(width: dimension, height: dimension)
}
```

For me, `Constants.numberOfDaysInWeek` is naturally `7`, and `Constants.minimumInteritemSpacing` is equal to `2`, but those can be any numbers you desire.

Comment: @DuncanC I'm not sure, either, but I still hope others can benefit from it, even if someone dislikes it for some reason:) Thanks!

Comment: @Fengson My answer was merely a suggestion to guide you to use the correct API for your use case. And it is great that you actually cared to post a working solution based on that rather than keeping it to yourself. Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and that will provide you a chance to customize the frame for all items within the collectionView.

```
import UIKit

class LeftAlignCellCollectionFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return nil }
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return nil }
        
        var newAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
        let leftMargin = self.sectionInset.left

        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout
        
        for attribute in attributes {
            if let cellAttribute = layout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: attribute.indexPath) {
                // Check for `indexPath.item == 0` & do what you want
                // cellAttribute.frame.origin.x = 0 // 80
                
                newAttributes.append(cellAttribute)
            }
        }
        
        return newAttributes
    }
}
```

Now you can use this custom layout class as your flow layout like following.

```
let flowLayout = LeftAlignCellCollectionFlowLayout()
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Origin of first item changes, but the rest stays as is, therefore first overlaps the second and the rest remain as they were. Shifting them all doesn't work either. I've edited my answer with a result your code yields for me. Any ideas?

Comment: You are in-charge of the complete layout as soon as you subclass flow layout. You should not expect a mix-and-match (choose only first item frame the custom subclass and do the default for the rest). You have to do the default as well in your subclass. This would be as simple as asking super implementation about attributes for an indexPath, shift it's x value, if it goes out of bounds horizontally, move to next line (shift y as well). Think of it like you are laying out every single cell/item rather than changing it for first cell only.